# Translating $X_1, \dots, X_n \subseteq [0,1]$ to cover $[0,k]$ with every $ x \in [0,1]$ in at least $k$ of the $X_i$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, geometry, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Let $k$ and $n$ be positive integers with $k \leq n$. Suppose that $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n$ are distinct subsets of $[0,1]$ such that for all $x \in [0,1], \#\{j \in \{1, \dots, n\} \ | \ x \in X_j \} \geq k$. I.e., every $x \in [0,1]$ is in at least $k$ of the $X_i$.

Is it possible to find integers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n \in \{0,1,\dots, k -1\}$ such that $a_1 + X_1, a_2 + X_2, \dots, a_n + X_n$ covers $[0,k]$?

I have drawn some simple examples when $k = 2$ and $n = 3$. For instance  $X_1 = [0,1], X_2 = [0, \frac12], X_3 = [\frac12, 1]$. There are multiple ways to shift the $X_i$ by integral amounts to cover $[0,2]$.

In simple cases like these, is possible, and the $a_i$ can be chosen in multiple ways. For the general case, I am hard pressed to find a method to decide what the $a_i$ should be. Intuitively, the result seems true.

Define $S_x := \{j \in \{1, \dots, n\} \ | \ x \in X_j \}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$. We can define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $[0,1]$ with $x \sim y$ iff $S_x = S_y$, and consider a finite, full set of representatives $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_m$ for the equivalence classes (there must be finitely many equivalence classes since there are finitely many possibilities for $S_x$, $x \in [0,1]$).

Perhaps considering this equivalence relation could shed some light on a proof, but so far I haven't made any progress.

My questions are:

- Is it possible to find such $a_i$?
- If it is not possible in general, is there some condition we can impose on the $X_i$ to make it possible to find such $a_i$ (e.g. Lebesgue measurability, openness, etc.)? Or by relaxing the condition that the $a_i$ are integers?

This question stems from a homework problem for measure theory which is easy to solve with the Lebesgue integral, but we haven't covered that in class yet, so I am asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I have a counterexample.
The counterexample is kind of built on your example that you have given.
So for k=2, n=4, consider the following sets,

$$  X_1=[0,1]-\{1/3\} $$
$$ X_2=[0,1/2]-\{1/4\}$$
$$ X_3=(1/2, 1]$$
$$ X_4=\{1/3,1/4\}$$.

With a little trial and error, you should be convinced that does not have any solution. You can also prove it by some contradiction. So you will need some more conditions on $X_i$'s to ensure this.